# What are the *new* different game modes?

Tags: dont-starve-together

Recently on starting up Don't Starve Together, there's a whole new set of server playstyles:

- Social
- Cooperative
- Competitive
- Madness

What changes do these make to the game?

Comment: I think it's purely to find server, no game play differences. I think, not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are just extra filters for searching for a server. They do not provide any practical use.

Comment: This is my impression as well.  I haven't noticed any gameplay differences.